# qt: QInputDialog::getText don't work

Tags: c++, qt, settext

I have this code:

```
bool ok;                
QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("Set Text"), tr("Text:"), QLineEdit::Normal, this->text(), &ok);

if (ok && !text.isEmpty()) 
{
   this->setText(text); 
   aggiorna_text_t();
}
```

But the result is that the window, and the buttons are totally black, only the text is visible and when I change the text the window don't repaint it so the text is overwrite.

What is wrong?

Comment: What platform? Are you using style sheets or palette modifications?

Comment: I don't think that this can be answered without any more details about the platform and the rest of the project. Do you have a minimal example where this code does *not* work?

Comment: I'm using window and style sheets modifications for other qt object. This is a QLabel, and when a click with mouse appaer the menu where I can set text.

Comment: Thank you cbamber85 for your indication, I added this line at the top of the code and now QInputDialog work fine.                      this->setStyleSheet( "QMenu {background-color: rgba(255,255,255,255);}" );

Comment: @user1439500 Please describe what you did in more detail in an answer (you can answer your own questions), so people who are in the same situation can be helped.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve it I added this line:

```
bool ok;            

**this->setStyleSheet( "QMenu {background-color: rgba(255,255,255,255);}" );**
QString text = QInputDialog::getText(this, tr("Set Text"), tr("Text:"), QLineEdit::Normal, this->text(), &ok);

if (ok && !text.isEmpty()) 
{
   this->setText(text); 
   aggiorna_text_t();
}
```